# R SelectizeInput - similar solution of ChoiceValues ChoiceNames?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, selectize.js

I am working on a small  R/shinydashboard project where I have to deal with ID and names: e.g. Warehouse_ID = 1, 2, ... --> Warehouse_Name = Toronto, Berlin,...
Since I generated these values from a dataframe, I used:

`list_dc_id = unique(dc$id)` and `list_dc_name = unique(dc$city)`

I want to use `list_dc_id` and `list_dc_name` to generate the value and shown name with SelectizeInput/updateSelectizeInput(Server=TRUE).

I was able to use checkboxGroupInput with ChoiceValues ChoiceNames to do a check box, however, I am searching for a solution with selectize. I saw some other help pages but unfortunately wasn't able to fully understand the solution.
Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `?shiny::selectInput`:

> choices:   List of values to select from. If elements of the list are
> named, then that name — rather than the value — is displayed to the
> user.

So you have to do `choices = setNames(list_dc_id, list_dc_name)`.